# not able to insert data into database mysql after extracting from other page

Tags: php, html, sql, dom

trying to insert data from content news in website.
Below are content of page source, m trying to insert data after extracting from this page.

Example of page source of website that i want to extract

```
<html>
    ...
    <div class=story-box>
    <img src="http://www.example.com/assets/images/CM.gif">
       <h2>Heading</h2>
       <p>afsdfdfha adhfaksdhf adfhakhf adfhaskfdha fsahfkasdhfaasfdjhasdf ahdfkahsd</p>
       <p>afsdfdfha adhfaksdhf adfhakhf adfhaskfdha fsahfkasdhfaasfdjhasdf ahdfkahsd</p>
       <p>afsdfdfha adhfaksdhf adfhakhf adfhaskfdha fsahfkasdhfaasfdjhasdf ahdfkahsd</p>
       <p>yuoyuouoyuoyuyu oyuiouioyuioyuyiouyoiy youyoiyuioyuioyuyoiuyiuyiyuioyu yuyiu</p>
    </div>
    ...
    </html>
```

i want to extract and insert into database of contents of heading (inside tag), image(inside tag), all content in p tags.

```
<?php
    include('simple_html_dom.php');
    $url = 'http://www.example.com';
    $html1=file_get_html($url);
    $heading=$html1->find("div.story-box h2",0);
    $heading1=strip_tags($heading);
    echo $heading;

    $image=$html1->find("div.story-box img",0);
    $image1=strip_tags($image);
    echo $image;
    $content=array();
    foreach($html1->find('div.story-box p') as $e)
    {
    $content=$e;
    $content1=strip_tags($content);
    echo "$e <br>";
    }
 ?>
```

This are process of inserting into database after above php codes

```
if(isset($_GET['submit']))
    {
        $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if(! $connect )
            {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_select_db("test1");

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO test1 '.
       '(heading,image, article) '.
       'VALUES ( "$heading1", "$image1", "$content1")';
        $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $connect );
        if(! $retval )
        {
        die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        echo "Entered data successfully\n";
        mysql_close($connect);
    }
    ?>
```

this are my sql statement of making table of mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test1` (
  `heading` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `image` blob NOT NULL,
  `article` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

But inside database i get only $heading1 $image1 $content1 not actual data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VALUES fields needed quotes around them as they're a string. As the data your are entering into the database is unknown I have also added [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function around the data to protect you and to sanitise it.

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO test1 '.
   '(heading,image, article) '.
   'VALUES ( "'. mysql_real_escape_string($heading1) . '", "'. mysql_real_escape_string($image1) . '", "'. mysql_real_escape_string($content1). '")';
```

Comment: Thank you, after it changed i got this error Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sangma assures major reshuffle"","
The Minister have already made clear that they w' at line 1

Comment: Thank you @beingalex, data has inserted. But there is some problem only last line of article has enter not whole article and also actual image is not in database, in image column field it conatain "[BLOB - 0 B]". can you please suggest me for to solved it. Thank you!

Comment: You will want to post another question then :)

Comment: Thanks!! From you help i can insert data, can also insert whole article i remake the code. Only one problem left actual image not able to insert to database, i get only [BLOB- 0 B] in field. will try again if can't gonna post another question.

Comment: @RIco Please post that as a completely new question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quotes from the variable names in $sql, i.e. instead of "$heading" try $heading as that is the variable name.

Comment: but getting this error Could not enter data: Unknown column '$heading' in 'field list'

Comment: Did you change only the last part of the query, because that error says that you are trying to insert in the column with name '$heading', while the column name should be 'heading' instead. Did you update your $sql to something like the other answers below suggested - 



$sql = 'INSERT INTO test1 '.
   '(heading,image, article) '.
   'VALUES ( "'. $heading1. '", "'. $image1. '", "'. $content1. '")';

Answer (score 0):

Try your code by using something like that:

```
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO test1 '.
   '(heading,image, article) '.
   'VALUES ( '. $heading1. ', '. $image1. ', '. $content1. ')';
```

Just like you did before with "." string connector.